# Hadoop configuration properties

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I would like to understand how I can **create** new configuration properties in hadoop.

For eaxample: In hdfs-site.xml I would like to create a new property which helps set a parameter that affects the entire cluster.

I just need to know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `hdfs-site.xml` http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Similar like this you can find for other files

You can use below format

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```